# How do I make scripts in the main layout apply to an angularjs view when it loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to integrate angularjs to an existing site.
The problem is that I've transformed a section of the main page into an angular view but when this latter is loaded into the main page using `ng-route` the main page slider scripts that are located at the bottom of the main page do not seem to render in the loaded view.

Does anyone have an idea how to get through this.
Thanks.

```
</div>
</header>
<div data-ng-view></div>
<footer id="footer">
<div class="container">

(function() {
  var app = angular.module('hbcm', ['ngRoute']);

  angular.module('hbcm').controller('DsplController', function() {
    this.panel = 1;

  });

  app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        controller: 'DsplController',
        templateUrl: 'view1.html'
      })
      .when('/about-us/', {   
        templateUrl: 'about-us.html'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
})();
```

Comment: Formatted the code so it is readable

Answer (score 0):

create a controller to handle you template (View), and attach that controller in the Route configuration

```
$routeProvider.when('/somewhere',  { controller: TheNameOfYourController, });
```

Comment: Do I have to put something in the controller when I create it?

Comment: You can create the controller in a separate file (I recommend it) or just **create it in line like this:
{
    controller: function($scope) {
    }
}**

Comment: adding a compiler doesn't seem to resolve anything , the javascript i want executed doesn't rest in the view but on the shell page , it's <script> tags that link to external  js files